# Redirect a View with Push Notification in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, push-notification, uistoryboardsegue

My aim is writing a code that when a user gets a push notification, I want that user to be redirected to another view.
If the user comes with the push notification and if he has been first viewed the controller (welcome home screen etc. (but not logged in))

```
var rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! ViewController
rootViewController.performSegueWithIdentifier("hospitalSegue", sender: self)
```

This couple lines of code is working, however, if the user has been in another view controller (sign in/login/user page etc.) this piece of code doesn't work and redirect.
I tried everything and I still cannot come up with a solution. My final goal is this:

```
if let rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as? ViewController
{
    var rootView: UserViewController = UserViewController()

    if let window = self.window{
        window.rootViewController = rootView
    }

    rootViewController.performSegueWithIdentifier("hospitalSegue", sender: self)
    println(self.window?.rootViewController)
}
```

Can anyone give me an idea?

Comment: Sounds like a great Idea. How do you receive the push notifications? And maybe you can give us an overview of your views inside the InterfaceBuilder, it depends on your hierarchy, how to redirect to a differenct view.

Comment: Are you displaying a `UIViewController` modally ?

Comment: Use an NSNotificationCenter. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/

Comment: In app delegate(didReceiveRemoteNotification), raise a local notification, and show the anotherViewController wherever required by registering to local notification and check if this is present view controller shown on screen.

Comment: @jeraldo thank you, i solved with nsnotificationcenter!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer code is Objective-C, I want to talk about logic. To do this, when you are creating your push notification, you must set **userInfo** value to pass data with your push notification.

Use this delegate method :  `application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler`

You can decide if which view you want to show by handling **userInfo**

```
NSDictionary *segueDictionary = [userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"];

NSString *segueName=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",[segueDictionary valueForKey:@"segueName"]];

if([segueName isEqualToString:@"hospitalSegue"]) 
{
// implement your code to redirect
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer code is Objective-C,you can prentviewcontroller from app delegate using below method i was resolve this issue using below code:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
      [[self topViewController]presentViewController:nav animated:YES    completion:nil];
}

- (UIViewController*)topViewController {
    return [self topViewControllerWithRootViewController:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController];
}

- (UIViewController*)topViewControllerWithRootViewController:(UIViewController*)rootViewController {
    if ([rootViewController isKindOfClass:[UITabBarController class]]) {
        UITabBarController* tabBarController = (UITabBarController*)rootViewController;
        return [self topViewControllerWithRootViewController:tabBarController.selectedViewController];
    } else if ([rootViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
        UINavigationController* navigationController = (UINavigationController*)rootViewController;
        return [self topViewControllerWithRootViewController:navigationController.visibleViewController];
    } else if (rootViewController.presentedViewController) {
        UIViewController* presentedViewController = rootViewController.presentedViewController;
        return [self topViewControllerWithRootViewController:presentedViewController];
    } else {
        return rootViewController;
    }
}
```